# почему выводится двойка

Tags: javascript

есть алгоритм выведения всех простых чисел методом сравнения числа N со всеми числами до него:

```js
let gen = prompt("введите число, вы получите все простые числа от 2 до этого числа");
let check = true;
for (let i = gen - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
  check = true;
  for (let j = i - 1; j > 1; j--) {
    // if(j == 1) {
    //  break;
    // }
    if (i % j == 0) {
      check = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (check) {
    document.write(i + "<br/>");
  }
}
```

скажем, будет введено число 3. По идее двойка выводится никак не должна, ведь i == 2, а j == 1, это значит, что i будет делится на j без остатка:

```
if(i % j == 0) { //i % j == 0, где i == 2, j == 1
    check = false;
    break;
}
```

вследствие этого check == false и мы переходим к `if(check)`, который не даст возможности вывести i (i == 2). 
Однако мы видим, что при вводе 3 в переменную gen, двойка все же выводится как простое число, хотя она делится без остатка на j

Comment: 2 - это простое число

Comment: это математика и реальный мир работают так, но если, по-моему, остаток некого числа при делении на число N дает 0, то, в данном случае, это число не является простым. Каково бы ни было данное N.

Comment: Нет, это утверждение неверно, если `N` равно единице.

Comment: ведь при N равному единице также остаток от деления по модулю будет 0, но у меня явно указано в ```if (i % j == 0) check=false;```, что при остатке 0 не будет выведено данное число.

Comment: Любое целое число делится без остатка на `1`. Они все простые?

Comment: в алгоритме, как вы могли не заметить по какой либо причине, происходит проверка на делимость числа N на все числа до него, а не включая проверку только на делимость на 1.

Comment: Не хамите. Я отвечал на Ваш предыдущий комментарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... а j == 1, ...

Если так рассуждать, то у Вас ни одно число не вывелось бы.

```
for (let j = i - 1; j > 1; j--) {
                    ^^^^^
```

Comment: я не понял. Ведь переменная объявляется в цикле, не значит ли это, что она уже может использоваться? Или я не неправильно понял замечание?

Comment: @Степан `j` не равно единице

Comment: все равно не понимаю почему ```j``` не равно единице. Кажется если условие не выполняется, то объявление не происходит?

Comment: @Степан "объявление"? Потому что условие выполнения тела цикла - `j > 1`. Если `j` равно единице, цикл останавливается, и тело цикла не выполняется.

Comment: теперь я понял в чем проблема. Проверка происходит именно во втором цикле